# Locate elements with dynamic ids inside div using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have following elemenet in my web page and I am not able to click this element using selenium in python.

```
<input id="main:j_id118:submissions:12:j_id345" name="main:j_id118:submissions:12:j_id345" type="image" src="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif" onclick="disableWaiting();if(typeof window.clearFormHiddenParams_main=='function'){clearFormHiddenParams_main('main');}if(typeof window.getScrolling!='undefined'){oamSetHiddenInput('main','autoScroll',getScrolling());}" alt="">"
```

So far, I have tried the following but no success.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('img[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@src="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]').click()
```

Below is my full script.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 def dnsnet_login():
    browser=webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://read-iweb-124-rv.snaponglobal.com:8080/psaww-dnsangular/index.html#/login')
    time.sleep(2)
    user=browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    user.send_keys('NSC')
    password=browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.send_keys('nsc')
    login=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/div[3]/button')
    login.click()
    time.sleep(11)
    toggle = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-container"]/header/nav/a[1]/span')
    toggle.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[3]/a').click()
    time.sleep(7)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('img[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]').click()
```

All the lines are executing correctly except the last one. That is

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('img[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]').click()***
```

Could any one please help me locating this element

Comment: What is the output of `print(len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]')))`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I think, some part of the id must be static and unique, you can use that part to locate the element.

Comment: Hi Tarun,  Thanks for you time, The output of the print(len........))) is 0 zero.

Comment: Hi Gaurang,  I am getting following error                Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"img[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]"}

Comment: HI, it's a input Tag, not img tag . you should use input[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"], not img[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"],

Comment: Hi yong,  I did try this(input[src*="/psaww-dnsangular/icons/excel.gif"]) as well but it is also not working giving me same error.   Thanks, Ansh

Comment: what part of the name or id says static, could you load the page multiple time (hard refresh) and check that. also increase the`sleep` time and try this `input[src*="excel.gif"]`